# Is "Cloud build Custom Worker" available now?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm working on a project where I need to access VM instances from Cloud build to download dependencies.
**Cloud build uses worker pool** and it will reside outside the VPC so, its not able to go through firewall. 
Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue or help me with **Custom workerpool creating**.

Comment: I tried this but it gave error.                                                                                          ```gcloud alpha builds worker-pools create gcb-workers-pool \
  --project=projectID  \
  --regions=us-central1 \
  --worker-count=2 \
  --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
  --worker-tag=gcb-worker-imagebuilder \
  --worker-network-name=default \
  --worker-network-project=projectID  \
  --worker-network-subnet=default
```

Comment: **Error says:**           project is not whitelisted for this feature, please contact cloud-build-contact@google.com

Answer (score 1):

From **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/worker-pools/?hl=es#NOTES)**:

`gcloud alpha builds worker-pools create`

> **This command is currently in ALPHA and may change without notice. If this command fails with API permission errors despite specifying the right project, you may be trying to access an API with an invitation-only early access whitelist**.